# Is there a reason why "Excalibur" (Hollow Ataraxia) and "Everything is On Her Hand" (EXTRA) share a motif? Do any other Fate tracks use the motif?

Tags: music, fate-extra, fate-hollow-ataraxia

Specifically, this one:

[image: A sheet music snippet of the motif in question.]

It appears at roughly 1:03 in the Hollow Ataraxia track (immediately following the section that FGO uses as regular Saber Altria's NP BGM), and at 0:33 in the EXTRA track. NUMBER 201 don't normally seem to reuse motifs unless the tracks are related in some way, so I wondered if there's some connection I'm missing? (Even one as small as "the song appeared in promotional material back when they were trying to convince everyone Nero was actually Altria.")